# PHP: Can't access object from included file

Tags: scope, php

Using this function I want to create a PHP navigation:

```
function loadPage($pagename) {
        if (!isset($pagename) || !file_exists($pagename . '.php')) {
            include FRONTPAGE . '.php';
        } else {
            include $pagename . '.php';
        }
    }
```

In my index I have the following:

```
require 'includes/classes/core.php';
$core = new SH_Core();
```

I can access all the other classes from $core like $core->database->newConnection();
And I should be able to use that in the included file too. But I can't:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: core in C:\Users\Development\Development applications\localhost\htdocs\Shuze\frontpage.php on line 4

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\Users\Development\Development applications\localhost\htdocs\Shuze\frontpage.php on line 4

Fatal error: Call to a member function newConnection() on a non-object in C:\Users\Development\Development applications\localhost\htdocs\Shuze\frontpage.php on line 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give your function access to $core:

```
function loadPage( $pageName ) {
    global $core;
    //rest of code
}
```

You could also put  at the top of your include file as well.  Or, you can use the super-global $GLOBALS['core'].

Comment: Thanks! This worked indeed! Stupid I missed that out.. Can't stop learning, haha.

Comment: Thank you for sharing.This is a very important rule.

Comment: -1: worst possible solutions

Comment: @tereško, why are you downgrading me for answering the guys question?  If he wants to use globals, that's the way you do it.  Yes, dependency injection, etc., would be better, but he wasn't asking a question about architecture.  So, if you're going to -1 me, please elaborate on how I was failing to answer the question or provide your "better" solution on how to access globals.